# Given a theorem "P(t) ⟶ (∃x . P(x))" with an object logic implication, why is the proof goal "P(t) ⟹ (∃x . P(x))" given with meta-logic implication?

Tags: isabelle

I am just starting with Isabelle/HOL and trying to prove a simple HOL statement "P(t) ⟶ (∃x . P(x))" with natural deduction rules. I started with a theory file containing just the theorem:

```
theory simple imports Main
begin

lemma T: shows "P(t) ⟶ (∃x . P(x))"
proof
  (* x *)
qed  

end
```

At the position marked x in the comment, the current goal is already "P(t) ⟹ (∃x . P(x))", i.e. the logical implication is already simplified to meta-logical implication.

Via trial and error, I came to the following proof:

```
proof
  assume "P(t)" then
  have "∃ x . P(x)" by (rule exI) then
  have "P(t) ⟶ (∃x . P(x))" by (rule impI)
  then show "P(t) ⟹ (∃x . P(x))" by (rule impE)
qed
```

which looks somehow odd: I am introducing the implication, just to eliminate it in the next step.

My questions now are:

1. Where does the rewriting of my goal come from and where can I find more about it?
2. How would I simplify the proof (without circumventing ND by using auto)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where does the rewriting of my goal come from and where can I find more about it?

When you use `proof` like that, it applies one simple step towards your goal. In your case, it applies `rule impI`. If you do not want that, use `proof -`.

But you probably *do* want to use the implicit `rule impI` here. Note that it changes your goal, and you can just write:

```
proof
  assume "P(t)"
  then show "∃ x . P(x)" by (rule exI)
qed
```

Which answers your second question.